# Changing the CiviCRM Theme in Drupal

Tags: drupal, theme

Currently running CiviCRM 4.6.8 and Drupal 7.

I want my Civi theme to be different than the one I'm using for the Drupal front end. I'm all but certain I used to be able to do this through Drupal's "Appearance" tab. In fact, I've read a couple of things after Googling it that suggest that there's an option to change Civi's theme in *admin/appearance*, but I don't see that option.

I also saw some articles mentioning an extension or a module that will do exactly what I'm looking for. I'll use it if I have to, but I'd rather use whatever features are included if I can.

Thanks for any advice!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to enable the civicrm theme module, that allows you to to set specific themes for backend and frontend pages. You don't need to download it, it's already there, you just need to enable it.

By default, it's the same theme that the other "normal" drupal pages and you need to have enabled the themes you want to assign to civi

Comment: The only module I can see for CiviCRM Theme is only available for Drupal 6. On that page (https://www.drupal.org/project/civicrm_theme) it says that the this functionality has been integrated into CiviCRM core and is available in my version.

Comment: what Xavier is saying is that you go to modules and enable this module CiviCRM Theme and after that go to appearance, somewhere at the bottom, you will get the option to use a different theme for CiviCRM

Comment: Ahah! Sorry to doubt you, Xavier. Feel like a dolt, now... Thanks a bunch!